# React components are overriding my stylsheet

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want my entire body background to be red color. So I added this line in my index.html file in Javascript public html file:

```
<link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now I did this to styles.css which is placed in same public directory:

```
body
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

So what I observe is that when I place my stylesheet linking in head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
```

it loads the background but then suddenly it disappears, but when I place the same stylesheet at the bottom of the body, it then loads.

```
<body>
<link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</body>
```

Does anyone know which default event is causing this issue and what could I do to keep my background red by keeping my stylesheet at the top as I want to load my page completely before it begins functionality.

Comment: Sounds like something else is loading AFTER the stylesheet in the head and placing it further down replaces that something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using stylesheets inside your react application which are exposed after the first `<link>` tag where you declare your body color.

If you declare it at the bottom of the html, it will be read at last which means that it will override all other equivalent styles (previously declared inside react code).

If you want to force it, use `!important` but the correct way is to set it inside the react code where you declare all other css styles.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to set it inside but the problem is that it won't render whole html body but only the certain parts, like for example app.js stylesheet renders only a fraction of what I want.

Comment: @ShivamSahil so you must check how "wide" your css is. if it applies to all application parts or to specific components.